# Multiple IF AND statements in one line with OpenOffice Calc

Tags: if-statement, openoffice-calc

I'm using multiple IF AND statements in one cell and finding operator missing error 509. It worked with fewer variables just not sure the syntax is correct for calc here.

tried using nested statement with error 509 returned as well.

=IF(M5="Statement 1";L5;K5)IF(AND(M6="Tax";A5=A6); | L6;K6);IF(AND(M7="Discounts";A7=A6); | L7;K7);IF(AND(M8="Alternate";A8=A7); | L8;K8);IF(AND(M9="Other";A9=A8); | L9;K9);IF(AND(M10="Local";A10=A9); | L10;K10);IF(AND(M11="State";A11=A10); | L11;K11)

Desired outcome: Trying to get this output pending all values are true: L5 | L6 | L7 | L8 | L9 | L10 | L11

Current outcome: Error:509 which is Operator Missing error.

Comment: Use **&** to concatenate strings `=IF(A1=1;"A1 is 1";"A1 is not 1") & "|" & IF(A2=2;"A2 is 2";"A2 is not 2")`

Comment: perhaps this is more like what you want? `=IF(M5="Statement 1";L5;K5)&IF(AND(M6="Tax";A5=A6); "|" & L6;K6)&IF(AND(M7="Discounts";A7=A6); "|" & L7;K7)&IF(AND(M8="Alternate";A8=A7); "|" & L8;K8)&IF(AND(M9="Other";A9=A8); "|" & L9;K9)&IF(AND(M10="Local";A10=A9); "|" & L10;K10)&IF(AND(M11="State";A11=A10); "|" & L11;K11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IF(M5="Statement 1";L5;K5) **missing&** IF(AND(M6="Tax";A5=A6); **missing & followed by quotes** | **missing quotes followed by &** L6;K6) **; does not belong here should be &**;IF(AND(M7="Discounts";A7=A6); | L7;K7);IF(AND(M8="Alternate";A8=A7); | L8;K8);IF(AND(M9="Other";A9=A8); | L9;K9);IF(AND(M10="Local";A10=A9); | L10;K10);IF(AND(M11="State";A11=A10); | L11;K11)

```
=if(M5="Statement 1";L5;K5)&if(AND(M6="Tax";A5=A6); "|" & L6;K6)&if(AND(M7="Discounts";A7=A6); "|" & L7;K7)&if(AND(M8="Alternate";A8=A7); "|" & L8;K8)&if(AND(M9="Other";A9=A8); "|" & L9;K9)&if(AND(M10="Local";A10=A9); "|" & L10;K10)&if(AND(M11="State";A11=A10); "|" & L11;K11)
```